# create datetime client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have spent several days trying to figure out the best approach, but I am at an impasse.

I have a react application with nodejs/express backend. Our small company uses this application and all our work is in the TZ = 'America/Los_Angeles'. I use datetime in mariadb to store report dates, entry dates, modification dates, etc. Our server is located in Arizona, so TZ = 'America/Denver'. I am currently using new Date() client side and passing it to my server. When nodejs returns my dates, they are naturally 1 hour off due to timezone difference. In this situation, should the dates be created client side or server side before posting to my database?

I have experiemented with:

1. date.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles" }) client side and
   timeZone: "America/Denver" to force it back, but this is just sloppy.
2. process.env.TZ = 'America/Los_Angeles' server side in nodejs
3. passing new Date() in my nodejs post, but MariaDB shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00 since the date was not formatted properly
4. SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'; in MariaDB. I cannot set Global

Comment: As a rule of thumb I now aways store and work with all timestamps in UTC and then covert them to the client's local. This seems to have kept all the time craziness and bad times to a minimum. Sorry no good, solid answer here. Time is HARD

Comment: Work in UTC, converting to local only for presentation to users. That just 2 different zones is causing trouble shows the risks of your current approach becomes. Note that  'America/Los_Angeles' is not really a timezone, it's a representative location that infers following the offset changes, including historic and daylight saving, that have occurred in Los Angeles. I.e. it does not represent a single offset. It is a "zone" only in that it encompasses all places that have followed the same offsets over time as LA.